# Jquery - Can you stop a div from updating until action in div is done?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Using jquery I am calling a php page using an ajax call. I call this every 60 seconds. The ajax call calls the php script, php script gets the rows from the db, returns the result back to the ajax call and upon success jquery updates a div with the new data. My question is, can you have the div update part upon success detect if the user is doing an action in that div and not update that div until the person is done with that action?

For example if the rows displaying in the div allow you to edit the data in place using jquery and the person clicks a row to edit in place, I dont want the div to update with new data until the person is done updating that row. Is that possible in jquery?

Comment: It would help to see your actual code, but I would simply suspend that AJAX call whenever a user begins editing and restart it when they're done. If you're using `setInterval` to start the check every 60 seconds, use `clearInterval` to abort it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can catch focus or blur events and have something flag the form they're working on is "dirty" (which then the ajax call would check before performing any new updates).
Or you can re-work the UI to hide any forms until they initiate they want to change it (i.e. an update link that exposes the form) then flag "working" until they either save their update or cancel out of any changes.

Basically, what this site does when you want to in-line edit a post and go to leave the page "Your form is open, are you sure you want to leave the page" kind of warning.